# Unable to launch Carrot2 workbench in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, carrot2

When I tried to launch carrot2-workbench 64-bit linux executable in Ubuntu 14.04, I am getting an error as

```
2015-01-29 17:33:40,436 INFO  org.carrot2.workbench.core.WorkbenchCorePlugin: Changed instanceLocation to: file:/home/administrator/Downloads/carrot2-workbench-3.9.4/workspace/
2015-01-29 17:33:40,871 INFO  org.carrot2.util.xslt.TemplatesPool: XSLT transformer factory:         com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fbd91d622a1, pid=8214, tid=140454572275456
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/administrator/Downloads/carrot2-workbench-3.9.4/hs_err_pid8214.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's a bug in underlying libraries. There is no known workaround as of yet -- keep an eye on this issue:

http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/CARROT-1058

In the meantime I'm afraid your options are limited to running Wb in a virtual machine with an older Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you install ubuntu on virtual box in ubuntu 14.04? Please send me the link. And which version of Ubuntu shall I use?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials for doing this. Search for "virtualbox ubuntu install" and I'm sure you'll figure it out. There are also preinstalled VM images so you can just install VirtualBox and enjoy an installed system (there is always a question of security in such case, but the time saved may be worth the risk). http://virtualboxes.org/images/

Comment: This has been fixed. A recent snapshot build will work. http://download.carrot2.org/head/3.10.0-SNAPSHOT/